# Android NDK: how do you redirect syslog output to logcat?

Tags: android, android-ndk, syslog

I have a lot of existing C and C++ code to run on Android that uses syslog.  How do I get the output of syslog calls to appear in logcat?

(This is a dev-time only problem; I don't care if the solution isn't portable or can't be shipped.)

Note that using LOG_PERROR isn't very useful.  You can do:

```
openlog("mystuff", LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
```

The problem is that anyone using syslog assumes that they can also use openlog; you have to assume that your openlog (specifying LOG_PERROR) is going to get overwritten by existing calls to openlog.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look [here](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=218) to read how to use logging in native code and then replace you syslog function to output using this function.

Comment: This isn't practical unless you've got a tiny project with no external dependencies.

Comment: @James: Android is already quite unique environment (bion libc). If you can recompile your projects just add ‛-include syslogwrapper.h‛ to your ‛CFLAGS‛, where the header file contains ‛syslog()‛ and  ‘openlog()‘ remappings by ‛#define‛s. I would be surprised if Android even provided these two functions.

Comment: That link is now dead but a copy is on the waybackmachine http://web.archive.org/web/20120729145744/http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=218